# Divide my Oracle table into 5 parts randomly

Tags: oracle, random

I want to separete my Oracle table into 5 parts, these parts records will be selected randomly from the original table. Parts can contain the same results, it is not a problem.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with parst? There are no Oracle structures called parts yet, I suppose! Did you mean partitions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select a random sample of results from an oracle query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733652/select-a-random-sample-of-results-from-an-oracle-query)

Comment: Thanks a lot I use SELECT  * FROM    (         SELECT  *         FROM    mytable         ORDER BY                 dbms_random.value         ) WHERE rownum <= 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ORDER BY dbms_random.value` and then work out the number of total records and divide by 5 and use this to limit the number of row returned:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM mytable 
      ORDER BY dbms_random.value 
    ) 
    WHERE rownum <= (SELECT count(*)/5 from mytable)
```