# How to create a random 25% sample from a given table in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I gave the query:

```
select dbms_random.value 
  from table;
```

How do I get the 25% sample?

Comment: You can look here as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733652/select-a-random-sample-of-results-from-an-oracle-query

Answer (score 5):

The select statement allows that.

> The **sample_clause** lets you instruct the database to select from a
>   random sample of data from the table, rather than from the entire
>   table.
>
> Selecting a Sample: Example  The following query estimates the number
>   of orders in the orders table:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) * 10 FROM orders SAMPLE (10);
>
> COUNT(*)*10
> -----------
>          70
> ```

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2065953)

Comment: This answer is not a great format, could you please put detail into the answer as well as the link, it means future users who come across this question do not have to navigate away from SO to get the answer they need. It also mitigates the risk of the link becoming broken over time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT temp.*, COUNT(*) OVER () count_rows
    FROM temp ORDER BY dbms_random.value) 
WHERE rownum <= 0.25 * count_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT mytable.*
        ,NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value)
         AS quartile
  FROM mytable
  )
WHERE quartile = 1;
```