# Sampling in oracle

Tags: oracle, sample-data

I'm trying to take a sample from a insurance claims database.

For example 20% random, sample from 1 million claims data where provider type is '25' and year is '2012'. Data is in sqldeveloper.  I am a statistician with basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733652/select-a-random-sample-of-results-from-an-oracle-query

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SAMPLE` to get a random set of rows from a table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   claim SAMPLE(20) 
WHERE  type ='25' 
AND    year = 2012;
```

Comment: Thank you Alen for your reply.  sample() works fine when I do not use the where clause.  But it will not bring random sample once I specify provider type and year.

Comment: I have hunch this is because it is applying filters after sample is taken. to get around this do the filtering in a inner query then sample on that: ie SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM WHERE ...) SAMPLE(20). syntax is rusty so that may not work as wrtten but should express the idea

Comment: @hubson: `SAMPLE` only works on the table, not on an inline view.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a SAMPLE command built in. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM emp SAMPLE(25)
```

means each row in emp has a 25% chance of being included in the resulting set. NOTE: this does not mean that exactly 25% of the rows are necessarily selected

this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/datamining/entry/to_sample_or_not_to_sample_part_2) was a quick read on more details on sampling

Comment: @hubson_bropa. No SQL which is an ISO standard has a TABLESAMPLE clause with this syntax : TABLESAMPLE <sample method> ( percent_value ) [ REPEATABLE ( seed_value ) ] *with* <sample method> ::= BERNOULLI | SYSTEM. What you says is PL/SQL which is very far to the standard...

Answer (score -2):

With this you get a single line of a sample that is shown random.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE@ SAMPLE(10)
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```