# Select random sample of N rows from Oracle SQL query result

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I want to reduce the number of rows exported from a query result. I have had no luck adapting the accepted solution posted [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733652/select-a-random-sample-of-results-from-a-query-result).

My query looks as follows:

```sql
select
    round((to_date('2019-12-31') - date_birth) / 365, 0) as age
from
    personal_info a
where
    exists
        (
        select person_id b from credit_info where credit_type = 'C' and a.person_id = b.person_id
        )
;
```

This query returns way more rows than I need, so I was wondering if there's a way to use `sample()` to select a fixed number of rows (not a percentage) from however many rows result from this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sample your data by ordering randomly and then fetching first N rows.

DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM

```
select round((to_date('2019-12-31') - date_birth) / 365, 0) as age
From personal_info a 
where exists ( select person_id b from credit_info where credit_type = 'C' and a.person_id = b.person_id )
Order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
Fetch first 250 Rows
```

Edit: for oracle 11g and prior

```
Select * from (
    select round((to_date('2019-12-31') - date_birth) / 365, 0) as age
    From personal_info a 
    where exists ( select person_id b from credit_info where credit_type = 'C' and a.person_id = b.person_id )
    Order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
)
Where rownum< 250
```

Comment: I think `fetch frist N rows` is not available on the version of Oracle that I am using (I think it's 10g). Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch first` to return a fixed number of rows.  Just add:

```
fetch first 100 rows
```

to the end of your query.

If you want these sampled in some fashion, you need to explain what type of sampling you want.

Comment: I want to shuffle the results and fetch the first N rows. `fetch` does the job well, but I would have to re-index the row id, right? Is there no way to use `sample()` here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 12C, you can use the row limiting clause below

```sql
select
    round((to_date('2019-12-31') - date_birth) / 365, 0) as age
from
    personal_info a
where
    exists
        (
        select person_id b from credit_info where credit_type = 'C' and a.person_id = b.person_id
        ) 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Instead of 5, you can use any number you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no good way to do this in 10g except for the thread link you posted above. In order to adopt that you have to make sure to use order by in your inner query, otherwise it won’t work. But the issue is that the inner query would do a full table scan but in terms of output you would be able to limit the number of rows. Hope this helps!