# U-SQL random sample of rows

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-storage, u-sql

I hope you all can help me.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to take a random sample from a large Azure database so that I can run the files locally before deploying on Azure cloud. The steps are to first create a pseudorandom number, then just take the first X rows or first X% of rows.

**What I've tried**

I've read several posts including [stack overflow SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733652/select-a-random-sample-of-results-from-a-query-result), [stack overflow SQL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table), [SQL select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp), and [USQL Order By Fetch](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/Winter-2017-2018-ReleaseNotes/Winter2018-ReleaseNotes/Query%20Expr%20with%20ORDER-BY-FETCH/Extract-Order-By-Fetch.usql), but still have not figured the syntax out.

**Code:**

```
//ATTEMPT 1
SELECT * FROM @searchlog
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
//ATTEMPT 2
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *
    FROM @searchlog
    ORDER BY NEWID() DESC FETCH 10;
//ATTEMPT 3
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *,
           NEWID() AS newid
    FROM @searchlog;
//ATTEMPT 4
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *,
           newid() AS newid
    FROM @searchlog;
//ATTEMPT 5
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *,
           newid() AS newidwoot           
    FROM @searchlog;
//ATTEMPT 6
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *,
           Random() AS newidwoot           
    FROM @searchlog;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U-SQL has a `SAMPLE` operator so just add it to the bottom of your statement.  For example, this code generates a 10% uniform sample:

```
@outsearchlog =
    SELECT *          
    FROM @searchlog
    SAMPLE UNIFORM (0.1);
```

Sample is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/sample).  You do not need an additional row number if you use this approach.  If you do feel you need a row number then use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

I would question the use of U-SQL in the year 2021, particularly for new projects.  ADLS Gen 1 has been deprecated (retiring Feb 2024) and as you know, U-SQL is not compatible with ADLS Gen 2.  So you should endeavour to convert your projects to use Azure Databricks or Azure Synapse Analytics or other suitable platform as soon as possible.

[image: U-SQL retired]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-overview

If you do consider switching to Azure SQL DB or Azure Synapse Analytics then that supports the `TABLESAMPLE` command for similar effect:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
TABLESAMPLE( 10 PERCENT );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very new to big data, so I had no idea USQL was being depreciated. Glad I asked!