# Select the table records based on the percentage of the column value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, window-functions, percentage

```
I have a table which has 1M records. I need to get 100K records randomly from the table based on a below criteria. Let assume the below table has 1M record, I need to get only 100K record from the table based on the region  i.e. 45% of record should be from AMER region 45K, 35% of record should be from EMEA -35K and  25% of record should be from APAC-25K. 100K = AMER( 45K ) + EMEA( 35K ) + APAC( 25K )


Example

| Region | Email |
| --- | --- |
| AMER | abc@abc.com |
| EMEA | abc1@abc.com |
| AMER | abc2@abc.com |
| APAC | abc3@abc.com |
| AMER | abc4@abc.com |
| EMEA | abc5@abc.com |
| AMER | abc6@abc.com |
| APAC | abc7@abc.com |
| AMER | abc8@abc.com |
| EMEA | abc9@abc.com |
```

I tried Window function

```
NTILE(10) Over(order by null)
```

which giving random 100K record. But I am not sure how to match the requirement to get 45K record from AMER region and 35K record from EMEA and 25K from APAC.

Comment: Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502153/1509264) from the linked duplicate `SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY dbms_random.value()) AS rn FROM table_name t) WHERE rn <= DECODE(region, 'AMER', 45000, 'EMEA', 35000, 'APAC', 25000)`