# Random records Select in mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name `tbl_Employees`

```
id  Name    Designation
1   Rajeev  Developer
2   Deepak  Developer
3   Pankaj  Sales
4   Siksha  Sales
5   Parul   Sales
6   Nikita  HR
7   Dinesh  Account
8   Mahiman Travel
9   Mukesh  Adevertising
10  Pulkit  Marketing
11  Diksha  Database
12  Gurinder    Database
```

I am using the select query as

```
select  * from tbl_Employees
```

Now I am trying to show 5 rows on my `.aspx` page. now my query is that the 5 rows data is randomly change on every `PageLoad` event.

Comment: select top 5 * from [tbl_Employees] order by newid()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select random sampling from sqlserver quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652064/select-random-sampling-from-sqlserver-quickly)

Comment: Because its a sample table and the amount of data is big and from that i have to select only 5 rows randomly :)

Comment: Please refer to this before proceeding : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NEWID()` to select records rendomly as below:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM tbl_Employees ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 5 * from [yourtable] order by newid()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  top(5) * from tbl_Employees order by newid()
```

Comment: i think it's lowercase of your ans, this is very important ;)

Comment: And i am confused that which ans i used to mark as answer :D